# is there any way to get key "last-modified" from zend Google Doc Adapter?

Tags: zend-framework, google-docs, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

I write some code like this to getting cell value in google Spreadsheet
this code exactly work

```
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_DocumentQuery();
$query->setSpreadsheetKey($this->spreadsheetId);
$feed = $this->spreadsheetService->getWorksheetFeed($query);
var_dump($feed);
```

but I need value of last modified this spreadsheet 
this value are protected in $feed object :

```
["Last-modified"]=&gt;
string(29) "Wed, 18 Sep 2013 08:58:44 GMT"
```

is there any way to get key "last-modified" of Goolgle Doc?
AND How i can access it via zend V.1?